# How can I set a cookie based on page ID in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Currently trying to have wordpress set a cookie based on particular pages.

I can set a general cookie from my functions file, and calling `add_action()` on the `init` hook.

```
/* functions.php */    
function setCookies(){
        global $post; 
        setcookie('test', 'it works');
        var_dump($post->ID);
    }

    add_action( init, setCookies(), 10);
```

The var_dump is returning `NULL`.

Is there a hook that will execute in time to set a cookie, but late enough to have information from `global $post;`

Comment: where (file) did you put that code ?

Comment: In functions.php, just made an edit to indicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$post` variable isn't set until you're inside the loop. Most themes have already generated output by the time you get there, so you won't be able to ever use that to set a cookie.

However, you should be able to hook into the `wp` action after the query is returned and set a cookie using your own custom loop. Try something like this:

```
function setCookies() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
       $post_id = $wp_query->current_post;
       setcookie('post_id', $post_id);
    }
    $wp_query->rewind_posts();
    return;
}
add_action( 'wp', 'setCookies', 10);
```

See the [Actions Run During a Typical Request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) and the [WP_Query Class Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) in the codex.

Comment: why you need `rewind_posts` ?